# CircleType text remove whitespace after rotateY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having this code:

```
<div id="curvy">
    This is the curved text
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.2.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
<script>
const circleType = new CircleType(document.getElementById('curvy'));
circleType.dir(-1).radius(1100);

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var counter = 1;
    var deg = -40;

$($($('#curvy div').find('span')).get().reverse()).each(function (index, value ) {
/* var css = $(this).css('transform');
css = css + ' rotateY(-50deg)'; */
if(counter > 5) {
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('');
    $(this).css('display','flex');
    $(this).css('vertical-align','top');
    console.log(text);

    //$(this).html('');
   var newElem = $('<span></span>').append(text);
   newElem.appendTo($(this));

/*    newElem.css('position','relative');
   newElem.css('z-index',counter); */
   newElem.css('vertical-align','top');
   newElem.css('transform','rotateY('+ deg +'deg)');
   deg = deg - 2.5;
}

//console.log(value);
counter = counter + 1;

});

});

</script>
<style>
html, body {
    font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
```

This is working fine but after I start rotating each letter using rotateY in its own span, the parent span seems to add a white space in between that I want to get rid of.

[Check jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz9jg7pp/)

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/ -  "In the HTML namespace, the transform property does not affect the flow of the content surrounding the transformed element." That is why, now lets see how to fix it. :)

Comment: Im not that sure of whats causing this since the generated code without the 3D rotation works without spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was approaching it totally incorrectly.

The issue wasnt the spans, the padding or any margins but the translateX or rotate value.

Since CircleType was using the initial size of the letter when rendering the effect, the manipulations that I did through jQuery later weren't taken into account by it.

I had to save the matrix and then decide if I would go for an increment on the rotate value or on the translateX value. I chose the latter because it felt less complicated to play with. Since I need that the rotation will begin after a specific amount of character, I use the appropriate checks.

```
<div id="curvy">
   Curved text
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.2.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
<script>
const circleType = new CircleType(document.getElementById('curvy'));
circleType.dir(-1).radius(900);

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var counter = 1;
    var deg = -40;
    var padding = 0;
$($($('#curvy div').find('span')).get().reverse()).each(function (index, value ) {
var css = $(this).css('transform').replace(/[^0-9\-.,]/g, '').split(',');
var x = css[12] || css[4];
var y = css[13] || css[5];

    var a = css[0];
    var b = css[1];
    var angle = Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI);

if(counter > 5) {
    if(counter >= 12) {
        padding = padding + 6 ;
    } else
        padding = padding + 4 ;
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(this).html('');
    $(this).css('display','flex');
   x = parseFloat(x) + padding;
   $(this).css('transform', 'translateX('+x+'px) rotate('+angle+'deg)');
   var newElem = $('<span></span>').append(text);
   newElem.appendTo($(this));

   newElem.css('transform','rotateY('+ deg +'deg)');
   deg = deg - 2.5; 
}

counter = counter + 1;

});

});

</script>
<style>
html, body {
    font-size: 30px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute; 
}
</style>
```

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz9jg7pp/18/)